# Admin On Rest show Custom Message from server after update

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

After updating a row, I want to show the custom message to the user.
I'm using this code: https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/reviews/ApproveButton.js

Admin-on-rest use [Material-UI Snackbars](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/snackbar) to show Message. How can I use this to show Custom Message from Server after an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're also using a custom saga to handle your actions, you can dispatch a notification using the `showNotification` action creator.

See the `reviewSaga` which works with this `ApproveButton` at https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest-demo/blob/master/src/reviews/reviewSaga.js